# Creating a proper Android Splash/Loading screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have an application that uses OpenGL on a GLSurfaceView. The problem
is that the initial load takes quite a while processing textures and
getting things ready.

What i want to do is have a simple PNG displayed (with a slight
animation) while the GLSurfaceView is getting ready. As soon as it's
ready to render, i would like to tear down the splash screen.

What is the right way to do this? I've tried ViewFlipper, ViewSwitcher
and a bunch of other things to switch between my R.layout.main view
and my GLSurfaceView but i can't seem to get it right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Make your `GLSurfaceView` be `android:visibility="invisible"` in your layout XML

Step #2: Put that `GLSurfaceView` inside of a `FrameLayout`

Step #3: Add an `ImageView` as another child of the same `FrameLayout`

Step #4: When the `GLSurfaceView` is ready, make the `ImageView` be invisible and make the `GLSurfaceView` be visible

Comment: I've tried doing this but I must be doing something wrong because every time I add the GLSurfaceView to the main.xml, it crashes when trying to run my activity. Do you have a sample or a reference link you can point me to?

Comment: Actually, i was able to get this to work but the problem is that the Renderer does not wake up and create it's surface if the view is invisible...

Comment: This does not work, as surfaceview is not being called, as its invisible

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did to overcome this situation...

I created a custom layout named loader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selectLevelID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loader"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

after that, I used this while creating the renderer for glSurfaceView

```
    public GlRenderer(Context ctx)
            {
loader_dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
loader_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loader);
loader_dialog.show()
//do your initializations....
loader_dialog.dismiss();
}
```

;

or just call `loader_dialog.dismiss();` after you loaded all your objects, textures etc...